# xamarin DateTimeOffset is wrong when device's language is Thai

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, xamarin

I created a xamarin form project and device's language is Thai.

Because when I call AWS4RequestSigner.Sign, it returns

"errorType" : "BadRequestException"

"message" : "Signature not yet current: 25631230T084059Z is still later than 20201217T084559Z (20201217T084059Z + 5 min.)"

I don't know why there is a difference in the below photo

[debug date time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P34GP.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your explanation is not enough to understand. You need to give an additional explanation of your problem.
Try to process DateTime with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture parameter.

Comment: Thailand is one of the few places in the world where .NET doesn't use the "normal" calendar but uses the ThaiBuddistCalendar (you can see it if you do `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetType()`)... So today is `31/12/2563` (`DateTime.Today.ToString()`) You see the year? 2563, not 2020. So to solve this problem, do as Noisy88 said.

Comment: Thanks, i use InvariantCulture and it works